# css: how to prevent absolutely positioned :after element from scaling during transition?

Tags: css, animation, css-animations, css-transitions

I have an `absolutely positioned` button on the bottom left cornor. The size is fixed at `15px width and height`.

The button has an `:after` element to increase the clickable area size.

When you hover over the button, the button expands. But this also increases size of the `:after` element.

How do you prevent the `:after` element from `scaling scale(1.5)` with the `button` element?

I tried playing around with `width` and `height` properties but this messes up the positioning.

```css
body {
position: relative;
height: 100vh;
padding:0;
margin: 0;
}

p {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

button {
      cursor: pointer;
      height: 15px;
      width: 15px;
      border-radius: 50%;
      color: white;
      border: none;
      background: #ffd86e;
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 15px;
      left: 15px;
      z-index: 10000;
    }

    button::after {
      content: '';
      /* z-index: -100000; */
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      height: 50px;
      width: 50px;
      transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
      background: transparent;
      border: 1px solid black;
    }

    button:hover {
      transform: scale(1.5);
      transition: transform 0.2s;
    }
```

```html
<p>element is left bottom corner</p>


<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Invert the styles applied I.E. apply the styles applied to the button to the `:after` element and vice-versa. because otherwise the `:after` element will also expand when hovered over the button

```css
button {
  position:relative;
  border:1px solid #000;
  display: block;
  padding: 1.5rem 2.5rem;
}

button::after {
  content: '';
  z-index: -100000;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: red;
  z-index: 10000;   
}

button:hover:after {
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%) scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}
```

```html
<p>element is left bottom corner</p>
<button></button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just create a second button which will act as a disguise. The button than you want has been given `class="orgBut"` and the disguised button which will be responsible for adding the borders is given `class="afBut"`.
Both have the same position and properties, just the `z-index` of `afBut` is set to `0` so that it goes behind the `orgBut`.

The `::after` selector is given to the `afBut` i.e. the disguised button which is behind your original button. And `hover` effect is given to the `orgBut`.

And that's it.
When you hover above the original button the cursor never goes to the button behind it and that is why the borders that you set are left un-affected.

The code is attached!!

```
`.orgBut {
  cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: #ffd86e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 10000;
}

.afBut {
    cursor: pointer;
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  color: white;
  border: none;
  background: #ffd86e;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 15px;
  left: 15px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.afBut::after {
  content: '';
  /* z-index: -100000; */
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  transform: translate(-50%, 50%);
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.orgBut:hover {
  transform: scale(1.5);
  transition: transform 0.2s;
}`

<p>element is left bottom corner</p>
<button class="orgBut"></button>
<button class="afBut"></button>
```

**Feel free for any further issues**